# Kubernetes: Linux user management

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes

We are running docker containers in Kubernetes. Docker allows to run containers under different users on host system level.

I was looking into several Helm charts and it seems that for example [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/master/Dockerfile) is running as "nobody", while [Grafana](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) is creating its user (hardcoded id) using *useradd* in Dockerfile.

Is there any way how to standardize the behavior in Kubernetes, possibly making sure that only users required on the system by containers are present? And removed once the container is scheduled elsewhere.

I am also worried that we will get userId collision, resulting in unexpected behavior, which will be hard to test...

Comment: If I understand correctly you need something like rbac to restrict users. This is supported in kubernetes https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/

Comment: RBAC afaik solves only restrictions on K8s resources (its API, pods, who can do deployments/changes etc.). What I am trying to solve are privileges on OS level, as containers and host are sharing the same kernel, users and groups. And if one container gets compromised, the attacker can escalate the attack to other containers on the given host.

Comment: Do you think it is more related to Docker containerization than to Kubernetes? This article might be helpful: https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Actually handling users in your infrastructure as a code is a development question. I am not asking how users work in *nix system, I have some idea. I am asking, what is the reasonable automation an app level. Is it some construct in IaC, is it additional init pod? Is the grafana approach the right one? Which will cause the least troubles, once I deploy my code into production. The world of sw development is not black and white. And once a system user is included, it is not necessarily a server administration question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't necessary for a container to have a user with UID that is used inside the container on a docker host machine.

Here is the example:

```
On the docker host machine:

# Mongo container is running
root@docker-test:~# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
08495ae15f44        mongo:latest        "docker-entrypoint..."   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       27017/tcp           some-mongo

# mongod process is running under UID 999
root@docker-test:~# ps aux | grep mongo | grep -v grep
999      14035  0.6  1.7 986136 67612 ?        Ssl  08:56   0:01 mongod --bind_ip_all

# there is no user with UID 999 id on the docker host machine
root@docker-test:~# cat /etc/passwd | grep 999
root@docker-test:~# 

Inside the container:

# attaching to container
root@docker-test:~# docker exec -it 08495ae15f44 bash

# mongod process is running with privileges of the mongodb user
root@08495ae15f44:/# ps aux | grep mongo | grep -v grep
mongodb      1  0.4  1.8 990320 70036 ?        Ssl  08:56   0:02 mongod --bind_ip_all

# user mongodb is present inside the container in /etc/passwd and has UID 999
root@08495ae15f44:/# cat /etc/passwd | grep mongodb
mongodb:x:999:999::/home/mongodb:/bin/sh
root@08495ae15f44:/#
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. The user space is shared on host kernel level, so if you run one containerA as user with id=1234, it is the same user as  user 1234 in containerB. This also means that any files you create are accessible (in both spaces). So if one container goes rogue, it is problem for others colliding. (but yes, the hard collision will not occur in this case. Only in Grafana style user creation)

Comment: https://medium.com/@mccode/understanding-how-uid-and-gid-work-in-docker-containers-c37a01d01cf

Comment: You mean, it's not all true. ) When your container is gone, there is no traces on the host docker machine of the user with UID you're using inside the container. So you don't need to bother to delete it manually afterwards. And you're right, if you have two containers, that are running with the same process UID they theoretically can access each other files if you configure the same shared directory for them, or if one of them escapes chrooted environment.

Comment: Thx, for clarification. But one more small thing: with prometheus we are talking about stateful component with access to host disk. So I suppose if Prom has UID=A, then all other components with UID=A (which escape the sandbox) can access the files? (even though Prometheus itself is long dead)

Comment: Pod has no access to host file system by default. File system access should be configured via volumes or special bindings (for example: https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/toolbox ). In case you are sharing Kubernetes cluster with someone you don't trust completely, you may want to configure Volumes using backends with additional authentication layer.